# PostGIS tables don't retain SRID

Tags: postgis, srid, geometry-data-type

I have multiple tables in a PSQL/PostGIS database which are comprised of GPS locations of animals. The tables are uploaded into the database with latitude, longitude, and timestamp columns, and then I create geometry columns from the latitude/longitude columns as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE main.gps_animals_data ADD COLUMN geom geometry;

UPDATE main.gps_animals_data 
SET   geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326), 22234);
```

In this way, I assumed my SRID was set to the EPSG projection **22234**, which is the UTM projection in my study area. However, when I try to do a simple spatial join between tables, I get a "mixed geometries" error (which I know means the tables don't share the same projection). I then try

`SELECT Find_SRID('main', 'gps_animals_data', 'geom')` , and it gives me 0.

I've tried updating my geometry column such as:
`UPDATE main.gps_animals_data SET geom = ST_SetSRID(geom, 22234);`

as well as creating a new geometry column from the coordinates (again) but assigning them an **4326** SRID (in case there's something wrong with 22234 for whatever reason), and I've also tried modifying my spatial join query to explicitly assign an SRID, such as:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
     ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(t1.longitude, t1.latitude), 4326), 
     ST_SetSRID(geom_wgs84, 4326)) distance_apart
```

No matter what, I keep getting:

> ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries CONTEXT:  parallel worker

Is there a reason that my tables are not storing the SRID's that I assign them, or are my commands not correct?

Comment: You really ought not be doing a `ST_SetSRID` on a stored column (more than once). If it's been set earlier to other than 4326, you need to `ST_Transform` to 4326.  Also, to get geodesic distance, you need to cast both to `geography`. And your `SELECT` is missing a `FROM` in your code block.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the geometry column to the table you need to set it's SRID

```
ALTER TABLE main.gps_animals_data ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, 4326);
```

Then PostGIS will know what is in that column when it comes to preparing your query.